# Getting response from SendMessage() + WM_COPYDATA

Tags: windows, mfc

Currently I am working on a sample which sends user data to the other process using WM_COPYDATA. I construct the COPYDATASTRUCT structure to fill the user data. And send the data to other process using SendMessage() function. The OnCopy() function returns true/ false value. But want to get other than the true/false(Like int, char[], float, etc).

Please help  me to getting the response from the other process other than true/false

Regards

Comment: So, you want to alter the return value type of a function in the Windows API? Good luck with that.

Comment: Cody Gray, i dont want to change the return value to be changed. but i want to get back the result responce other than true/ false.

Comment: So send another message back the same way you sent the original one. I still don't understand the question.

Comment: I understand the question immediately! I have the same problem. If one application sends data to another application the other application may want to respond with DATA not just a primitive BOOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi all you can to do its send response by SendMessage with COPYDATASTRUCT struct which consist your return data. You cant change SendMessage return type.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use SendMessageTimeout(SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG) rather than SendMessage()! Otherwise if the receiving process is hanging the sending process will also hang eternally!

Comment: SendMessageTimeout  depends on your protocol. Often you want hang the client eternally, and especially when debugging and one side triggers a breakpoint.